# Elastic Search completion suggester configuration

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch

I'm trying to set autocomplete/suggestions on my site's search form, using Elastic Search's [completion suggester](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) feature.

I have a list of products, which are grouped by categories (on multiple levels). The search feature should be able to suggest category names, which are of more interest to users than direct products.
Several of these categories have the same name but a different parent (e.g. '*milk*' under parent category '*dairy products*' and '*milk*' under category '*baby*'). When the user selects a category suggestion, she's redirected to another page, with more specific results than mere search method.

Additional metadata (url to redirect to, parent category id/name) are added in the `payload` field.

I use the `output` field to return normalized suggestions for different inputs. As stated in the documentation:

> "The result is de-duplicated if several documents have the same output,
>   i.e. only one is returned as part of the suggest result."

But as explained, my outputs may have the same value, while being different results, as they will link to different pages. It is also possible in the future that different category levels will yield different actions.

I am reluctant to differentiate things by adding the full string (i.e. *"milk in dairy products"*) as the output, because:

**1.** The parent category is conceptually not the output itself but a related metadata.
**2.** I intend to have some formatting in the results, this forces me to parse the output string to add HTML tags in it.

So, is it possible to deactivate the de-duplication?

One workaround I'm thinking of if it's not possible is to store a stringified json object in the output, with all the data 'll need, both the one displayed in the search form and the metadata currently in the payload. But Id' rather look into existing configuration before resorting to that.

Comment: If you have several different documents with the same output, how is the user supposed to know which one to choose?

Comment: That's where the payload data comes into play. Part of it is appended to the output, another part defines the behavior when the suggestion is selected.

Comment: Why don't you index your data with the payload-data attached to the output string? Instead of attaching it later on?

Comment: I consider the payload to be some kind of external metadata, and therefore conceptually should be outside the output string itself. But I guess I'll to include it anyway if that's the only option I have.

Comment: Not sure if it's the only way, but certainly the easiest one. Since you want to attach the data to your output anyway, why not attach it in the first place while indexing and it's all sorted out?

Comment: Sure I can add it, or at least the part that allows distinguishing outputs. But doing that means some parsing on the client side, to format the output correctly, which I don't need to do if the final output is built from the output and payload. I won't index some html-formatted document to avoid this, that seems worse.
Also, I was trying to be as generic as possible, since the data in payload may be used for other purposes in the future. I guess if we ever need it we'll re-index.

Comment: You might want to edit you question with some sample data to explain that better. Perhaps someone else has a solution for you :)

Comment: I have the same problem; in my case, the differentiation of the equally named strings is done dynamically depending on user input, so it can't be done at index time.